# How to rewrite this RegExp to not use deprecated API?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following `RegExp` `myRegexp`, that matches numbers in a string:

```
var myRegexp = new RegExp('[0-9]+');
```

Then I have the following code that extracts numbers from a string and returns an array:

```
var string = '123:456';
var nums = new Array();
while(myRegexp.test(string)) {
        nums.length++;
        nums[nums.length - 1] = RegExp.lastMatch;
        string = RegExp.rightContext;
}
```

Should return an array of two elements: "123", and "456".

However, `RegExp.lastMatch` and `RegExp.rightContext` are deprecated/non-standard API, and not portable. How can I rewrite this logic using portable JS API?

Thanks,

Comment: I see nowhere if they are deprecated. Doc emphasizes *non-standard*. And the properties are but the back-reference `$'` aren't.

Comment: Please add a realistic example and the regular expression you would like to use. It might be easier to guide you knowing what you're trying to do.

Comment: I've edited the question with an example.

Comment: `{string}.match(/\d+/g)` or in your case will better `{string}.split(':')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match all numbers in a string, you'd simply use `string.match(/\d/g);` to match all single digits in a separate array entry, or `string.match(/\d+/g);` to match as numbers. There's no need for any of the things you've tried to use…

```js
let string = "2kdkane2kdkie83kdkdk303ldld";

let match = string.match(/\d+/g);
let match1 = string.match(/\d/g);

console.log('numbers:', match);
console.log('single digits:', match1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `g` flag to perform a global match which will find all matches without having to repeatedly test the string.

```js
let s = '123:456'
const regexp = new RegExp(/\d+/g);
let nums = s.match(regexp);
console.log(nums);
```